# How to move 10,000 rows of data from a Stored Procedure to excel using c# winform

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, excel, openxml

The situation is as follows -

- UserX wants information about PlayerY.
- Currently I get details about PlayerY and run two sql scripts that return two data sets - each one being approximately 10,000 records.
- I then manually copy and paste these sets into an Excel workbook and email this to UserX

Current planned approach:

1. I will create a simple WinForm or WPF, for UserX, that will accept input of the details of PlayerY.
2. I will create two stored procedures that will accept input from the form.

How does the data get from the database to UserX's client?

I ask because the data sets are quite large and there may be unforeseen problems with certain approaches because of the size. Should the stored procs first move the data to actual server tables, then have a second step and move the data from the server tables into Excel? Or should I just have the stored procedures return the datasets as it will be easy enough to move them direct into XL without any intermediate server tables?

Comment: I think your first question should be, how does the data get from the database to UserX's client.

Comment: @Jodrell do you have an answer :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to fetch record thr' c#,

Instead of fetching 10000 or more records one at time, fetch specific no. of records eg 1000, 10 times. That will make process quicker & less memory load.

You don't need to create any intermediate server table to store dataset.

Using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet in c#, you can write that dataset to Xlsx format or create xml file using System.xml or use thrid party tool/create own excel xml, to create xls format.

Comment: xlsx is the format I want to move the data to - do you know of any examples of code used to do this?

Comment: Follow steps mentioned in this url : http://lateral8.com/articles/2010/3/5/openxml-sdk-20-export-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx .

Comment: is this on [CODEPLEX](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) the same as what you mention in your URL, but more up-to-date ?

Comment: Its upto you but you can easily create xlsx file using DocumentFormat.OpenXml libraries. It generates file with loads of data quickly within different worksheets. Have tested n happy with it.

Comment: still haven't had chance to test as still thinking about the project in it's entirety and how to tackle it. are the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` libraries a MS creation?

Comment: and in terms of formatting the data once it is in the xlsx file - is this a trivial matter? Can the formatting be done with this `OpenXml` library or should I use the `ExcelInteroperability` library ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create .csv file from the results returned by your stored procedure at run-time using C#, a .csv file can be opened in Excel so you still have excel as the application at the end

Also please see this link hence i did not recommend you using Automation of Office

> **Paragraph taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757** Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Comment: ...the csv is returned, in memory, from the stored procedure? or is the csv saved to the filesystem?

Comment: @whytheq you will have right the code to create .csv and save